# Network Render appears to only use one slave at a time

Tags: rendering, network

Blender 2.76rc3, I setup a single master, 6 slaves and one client. The processing properly distributed jobs across the slaves, however only one task is active at a time. When one slave completes another usually gets the next chunk. So there are never more than one active slave processing the task. Is it possible to have all slaves active processing portions of the render job? I may have missed something in the configuration or setup? Thank you.